# How do I configure gitVersion to increment patch per commit on release branches

Tags: branching-strategy, gitversion

We are following trunk based development approach, where when a feature is ready, we merge it to master and create release branch with semantic version, so we have full control on major/minor/patch versioning,
eg :
release/1.0.0 .
release/1.0.1 etc ..

We run gitversion on our build step which is considering versioning provided in branch name and creating version based on it (default gitversion behavior), and we propagate to our lower systems
We tag this version only once it got successfully deployed to production (last stage in our ci/cd workflow)

The issue I am seeing right now is when cherry picking bug fixes and merging to release branch which is not tagged yet. (typical trunk based approach)

the behaviour I was looking for is  as follows:

assume release/1.0.0 (current tagged release branch) ,gitversion - appname-1.0.0-rc.1 . 
After a bug fix merged to master
- cherry-pick bug fix commits from master , merge to release/1.0.0
- gitversion bump patch value to appname-1.0.0-rc.2
- new commit on release/1.0.0 branch
- gitversion bump patch value to appname-1.0.0-rc.3

Instead, I am seeing the following behaviour:
- cherry-pick bug fix commits from master , merge to release/1.0.0
- gitversion doesn't increment patch value, semantic version stays at appname-1.0.0-rc.1
- new commit on release/1.0.0 branch
- semantic version stays at appname-1.0.0-rc.1

Here are the configs I m using
[GitVersion.txt](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/files/3613910/GitVersion.txt)

Comment: it's hard to understand without a simple graph. could you add a git tree graph with an example?

Comment: I'm confused by this behavior as well. It's unclear how to, without explicit tagging, increment the patch on the release branch. I would have expected this to have been supported if in `ContinuousDeployment` mode, but that doesn't do it. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

GitVersion has a hierarchy it uses for determining the calculated version, all defined by the various default branch configurations, which can be seen by executing `GitVersion /showConfiguration`.

It seems like you need to customize your configuration based on your team's workflow and branching model in order to achieve the desired behavior.